# WAI-ARIA : Event if aria-hidden=true MS windows narrator reads text from UI

Tags: angularjs, accessibility, wai-aria

We are using WAI-ARIA in our web application for accessibility. We came across one scenario is that Windows narrator reads out all the contents from screen even if those are marked as hidden.
To resolve this i tried below solutions,

1. `<span style="visibility: hidden;display:none;" aria-hidden="true">Loading..</span>`
2. `<span style="width:0px;height:0px;font-size:0px;line-height:0 " aria-hidden="true">Loading..</span>`

Referred :

http://juicystudio.com/article/screen-readers-display-none.php#comment3

http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/#absolutepositioning

https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2012/05/html5-accessibility-chops-hidden-and-aria-hidden/

Then also Windows narrator reads it out. So my requirement is that how we can hide the text from windows narrator so that it should not read my hidden text and messages?

Any suggestions?

Comment: try the html `hidden` attribute and share your findings. `<span hidden style="display: none">Loading...</span>`

Comment: This is a bug in Windows Narrator. You should report the bug and then stop using that screen reader until it is viable. Not reading text that is display:none is a VERY BASIC accessibility technique and without it, Narrator is not a viable accessible platform.

Comment: This isn't a bug only in narrator. I have tested in both JAWS and NVDA, which holds a very large market share of screen reader software and no matter what browser these are paired with ( I tested Chrome, IE11, Firefox with both screen readers ), the element marked with aria-hidden still gets read out to the screen reader user. I happened upon some of the same articles you have listed above. It appears that screen readers or browser accessibility APIs don't respect aria-hidden. I hope I'm incorrect really quick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Angular, you could use `ng-if` to add/remove items from the HTML. If the `ng-if` condition is FALSE, the items are removed from the DOM so will not be read:

```
<span ng-if="conditionSuchAsNotYetLoaded">Loading..</span>
```